# How can I count the instances of an object?

Tags: javascript

If i have a Javascript object defined as:

```
function MyObj(){};

MyObj.prototype.showAlert = function(){
   alert("This is an alert");
   return;
};
```

Now a user can call it as:

```
var a = new MyObj();
a.showAlert();
```

So far so good, and one can also in the same code run another instance of this:

```
var b = new MyObj();
b.showAlert();
```

Now I want to know, how can I hold the number of instances MyObj?
is there some built-in function?

One way i have in my mind is to increment a global variable when MyObj is initialized and that will be the only way to keep track of this counter, but is there anything better than this idea?

**EDIT:**

Have a look at this as suggestion here:

[image]

I mean how can I make it get back to 2 instead of 3

Comment: What happens when an object goes out of scope?

Comment: Don't add a global variable as a counter, add a property to `MyObj.prototype` or `MyObj`, or add a private variable via a closure. (None of which solve the problem Lee Taylor mentioned.)

Answer (score 20):

There is nothing built-in; however, you could have your constructor function keep a count of how many times it has been called.  Unfortunately, the JavaScript language provides no way to tell when an object has gone out of scope or has been garbage collected, so your counter will only go up, never down.

For example:

```javascript
function MyObj() {
  MyObj.numInstances = (MyObj.numInstances || 0) + 1;
}
new MyObj();
new MyObj();
MyObj.numInstances; // => 2
```

Of course, if you want to prevent tampering of the count then you should hide the counter via a closure and provide an accessor function to read it.

**[Edit]**

Per your updated question - there is no way to keep track of when instances are no longer used or "deleted" (for example by assigning null to a variable) because JavaScript provides no [finalizer methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalizer) for objects.

The best you could do is create a "dispose" method which objects will call when they are no longer active (e.g. by a [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) scheme) but this requires cooperation of the programmer - the language provides no assistance:

```javascript
function MyObj() {
  MyObj.numInstances = (MyObj.numInstances || 0) + 1;
}
MyObj.prototype.dispose = function() {
  return MyObj.numInstances -= 1;
};
MyObj.numInstances; // => 0
var a = new MyObj();
MyObj.numInstances; // => 1
var b = new MyObj();
MyObj.numInstances; // => 2
a.dispose(); // 1 OK: lower the count.
a = null;
MyObj.numInstances; // => 1
b = null; // ERR: didn't call "dispose"!
MyObj.numInstances; // => 1
```

Comment: But: `var x = new MyObj(); x = null; alert(MyObj.numInstances);`

Comment: @nnnnnn: right, this simple strategy doesn't track the lifecycle of object instances, so the counter never gets decremented, even when objects are eligible for garbage collection.  (Note that my own example demonstrates that the two anonymous instances are still counted even though they are not accessible.)

Comment: If you add a small note that it is a number of *created* instances - then no one would try to find any drawbacks ;-)

Comment: Oh perfect, this simply does what i needed to do, actually i didn't want the count outside but rather in the object itself, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: OH oh, actually i have come across same problem as suggested my @nnnnnn, so is there a way out of this, please check my question again

Answer (score 4):

Create a static property on the `MyObj` constructor called say `count` and increment it within the constructor itself.

```
function MyObj() {
    MyObj.count++;
}

MyObj.count = 0;

var a = new MyObj;
var b = new MyObj;

alert(MyObj.count);
```

This is the way you would normally do it in say Java (using a static property).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is very reliable method. you assume MyObj is accessible from global space. This might not always be the case.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What does scope have anything to do with this solution?

Answer (score 3):

```
var User = (function() {
   var id = 0;
   return function User(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.id = ++id;
   }
})();

User.prototype.getName = function() { 
    return this.name; 
}

var a = new User('Ignacio');
var b = new User('foo bar');

a
User {name: "Ignacio", id: 1}
b
User {name: "foo bar", id: 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [**ES6 Classes** <sup><sub>*MDN*</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) syntax - we can define a `static` method:

> The `static` keyword defines a static method for a **class**. Static methods are called without instantiating their class and cannot be called through a class instance. Static methods are often used to create utility functions for an application.

```js
class Item {

  static currentId = 0;    
  _id = ++Item.currentId;  // Set Instance's this._id to incremented class's ID
                           // PS: The above line is same as:
                           // constructor () { this._id = ++Item.currentId; }
  get id() {               
    return this._id;       // Getter for the instance's this._id
  }
}

const A = new Item(); // Create instance (Item.currentId is now 1)
const B = new Item(); // Create instance (Item.currentId is now 2)
const C = new Item(); // Create instance (Item.currentId is now 3)

console.log(A.id, B.id, C.id);                     // 1 2 3
console.log(`Currently at: ${ Item.currentId }`);  // Currently at: 3
```

PS: if you don't want to *log*-expose the internal `currentId` property, make it **private**:

```
static #currentId = 0; 
_id = ++Item.#currentId;
```

---

Here's an example with `constructor` and without the getter:

```js
class Item {

  static id = 0;
  
  constructor () {
    this.id = ++Item.id;
  }

  getID() {               
    console.log(this.id);
  }
}

const A = new Item(); // Create instance (Item.id is now 1)
const B = new Item(); // Create instance (Item.id is now 2)
const C = new Item(); // Create instance (Item.id is now 3)

A.getID();   B.getID();   C.getID();       // 1; 2; 3
console.log(`Currently at: ${ Item.id }`); // Currently at: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

what about such method?

```
var Greeter = (function ()
{
    var numInstances;

    function Greeter(message)
    {
        numInstances = (numInstances || 0) + 1;
        this.greeting = message; 
    }

    Greeter.prototype.greet = function ()
    {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    };

    Greeter.prototype.getCounter = function ()
    {
        return numInstances;
    };

    return Greeter;

})();

var greeter = new Greeter("world");
greeter.greet();
greeter.getCounter();

var newgreeter = new Greeter("new world");
newgreeter.greet();
newgreeter.getCounter();

greeter.getCounter();
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping a global count variable and incrementing every time is an option. Another option is to call `counter` method after each instance creation by hand (the worst thing I could imagine). But there is another better solution. 
Every time we create an instance, the constructor function is being called. The problem is the constructor function is being created for each instance, but we can have a `count` property inside `__proto__` which can be the same for each instance.

```
function MyObj(){
    MyObj.prototype.addCount();
};

MyObj.prototype.count = 0;

MyObj.prototype.addCount = function() {
    this.count++;
};

var a = new MyObj();
var b = new MyObj();
```

This is our `a` and `b` variables after all: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, JS is going to have built-in proxy capability, which will have low-level access to all kinds of things which happen in the background, which will never be exposed to front-end developers (except through the proxy -- think magic-methods in languages like PHP).

At that time, writing a destructor method on your object, which decrements the counter might be entirely trivial, as long as support for destruction/garbage-collection as a trigger is 100% guaranteed across platforms.

The only way to currently, reliably do it might be something like creating an enclosed registry of all created instances, and then *manually* destructing them (otherwise, they will NEVER be garbage-collected).

```
var Obj = (function () {
    var stack = [],

        removeFromStack = function (obj) {
            stack.forEach(function (o, i, arr) {
                if (obj === o) { arr.splice(i, 1); }
                makeObj.count -= 1;
            });
        };

    function makeObj (name) {
        this.sayName = function () { console.log("My name is " + this.name); }
        this.name = name;
        this.explode = function () { removeFromStack(this); };
        stack.push(this);
        makeObj.count += 1;
    }

    makeObj.checkInstances = function () { return stack.length; };
    makeObj.count = 0;
    return makeObj;

}());


// usage:

var a = new Obj("Dave"),
    b = new Obj("Bob"),
    c = new Obj("Doug");

Obj.count; // 3

// "Dave? Dave's not here, man..."
a.explode();

Obj.count; // 2
a = null;  // not 100% necessary, if you're never going to call 'a', ever again
           // but you MUST call explode if you ever want it to leave the page's memory
           // the horrors of memory-management, all over again
```

Will this pattern do what you want it to do?
As long as:

1. you don't turn `a` into something else
2. you don't overwrite its `explode` method
3. you don't mess with `Obj` in any way
4. you don't expect any `prototype` method to have access to any of the internal variables

...then yes, this method will work just fine for having the counter work properly.
You could even write a general method called `recycle`, which calls the `explode` method of any object you pass it (as long as its constructor, or factory, supported such a thing).

```
function recycle (obj) {
    var key;
    obj.explode();
    for (key in obj) { if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { delete obj[key]; } }
    if (obj.__proto__) { obj.__proto__ = null; }
}
```

Note - this won't actually get rid of the object.
You'll just have removed it from the closure, and removed all methods/properties it once had.

So now it's an empty husk, which you could reuse, expressly set to `null` after recycling its parts, or let it be collected and forget about it, knowing that you removed necessary references.

Was this useful?
Probably not.

The only time I really see this as being of use would be in a game where your character might only be allowed to fire 3 bullets at a time, and he can't shoot a 4th until the 1st one on screen hits someone or goes off the edge (this is how, say, Contra worked, in the day).

You could also just shift a "disappeared" bullet off the stack, and reuse that bullet for any player/enemy by resetting its trajectory, resetting appropriate flags, and pushing it back onto the stack.

But again, until proxies allow us to define "magic" constructor/destructor methods, which are honoured at a low-level, this is only useful if you're going to micromanage the creation and destruction of all of your own objects (really not a good idea).

Comment: Why keep the stack? You could simply decrement the counter

Answer (score 0):

My solution is creating an object store instance count and a function to increase them in prototype.

```
function Person() {
  this.countInst();
}

Person.prototype = {
  constructor: Person,
  static: {
    count: 0
  },
  countInst: function() {
    this.static.count += 1;
  }
};

var i;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var p = new Person();
  document.write('Instance count: ');
  document.write(p.static.count);
  document.write('<br />');
}
```

Here is my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/hPtIR2MQnV08L9o1oyY9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
        class Patient{
        
        constructor(name,age,id){        
            Object.assign(this,{name, age, id});    
            
        }
        static patientList = []; // declare a static variable
        static addPatient(obj){       
            this.patientList.push(...obj); // push to array
            return this.patientList.length; // find the array length to get the number of objects
        }
        
    }
    
    let p1 = new Patient('shreyas',20, 1);
    let p2 = new Patient('jack',25, 2);
    let p3 = new Patient('smith',22, 3);
    let patientCount = Patient.addPatient([p1,p2,p3]); // call static method to update the count value with the newly created object
   console.log(Patient.patientList);
    console.log(patientCount);
```